# select() marks a FD to be readable, but there is no data to be read

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, socket

I'm encountering an issue in my server code where calling `accept()` on the listening socket will occasionally block, even though `select()` marked it readable. My understanding is that this isn't a case that should happen often, if at all, but I'm not sure if there is a POSIX-standard guarantee on data being available when a socket is "readable". I am currently investigating my code logic for error, but was wondering if anyone had experience with this kind of issue and know what kind of scenarios would need to happen for this situation to arise? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. You cannot be sure that a connection still sits on the accept-queue if you do an `accept()` after a `select()` since the connection can already be terminated by the initiator or taken by another accepting process. From `man 2 accept`:

> There may not always be a connection waiting  after  a  `SIGIO`  is  delivered  or  `select(2)`, `poll(2)`,  or  `epoll(7)` return a readability event because the connection might have been removed by an asynchronous network error or another thread before `accept()` is called.  If this happens, then the call will block waiting for the next connection to arrive.  To ensure that `accept()` never blocks, the passed socket `sockfd` needs to have the `O_NONBLOCK` flag  set  (see `socket(7)`).

Comment: Great, thank you for the confirmation! I've been seeing similar issues on other single threaded applications, so the excerpt is especially illuminating.